# Finding recurrence relation for a sequence of polynomials

Tags: generating-functions

The sequence
[A059710](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A059710)
starts 1,0,1,1,4,10,35,... 
This satisfies the polynomial recurrence relation
$$ (n+5)(n+6)a(n)=2(n-1)(2n+5)a(n-1)+(n-1)(19n+18)a(n-2)+14(n-1)(n-2)a(n-3) $$
I have a $q$-analogue of this sequence. The first few terms are:
$$1$$
$$0$$
$$1$$
$$q^{3}$$
$$q^{6} + q^{4} + q^{2} + 1$$
$$q^{9} + q^{8} + 2 q^{7} + 2 q^{6} + 2 q^{5} + q^{4} + q^{3}$$
$$q^{14} + q^{13} + 4 q^{12} + 2 q^{11} + 5 q^{10} + 4 q^{9} + 5 q^{8} + 
2q^{7} + 5 q^{6} + q^{5} + 2 q^{4} + q^{3} + q^{2} + 1$$
$$q^{21} + q^{19} + 2 q^{18} + 4 q^{17} + 5 q^{16} + 9 q^{15} + 10 q^{14}
+ 13 q^{13} + 13 q^{12} + 14 q^{11} + 12 q^{10} + 12 q^{9} + 8 q^{8} + 7
q^{7} + 4 q^{6} + 3 q^{5} + q^{4} + q^{3}$$

These are $q$-analogues since if you put $q=1$ you get the original sequence.

Would anyone like to suggest a $q$-analogue of the polynomial recurrence relation?

I have asked a closely related question in 
[17610](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17610/)

I can calculate a few more terms than I have posted here.

Since you asked, the polynomial is constructed as follows: take $V$ to be the seven dimensional representation of $G_2$; take the invariant tensors in $\otimes^nV$;
take the Frobenius character of this representation of $S(n)$; take the fake degree polynomial of this symmetric function (almost the principal specialisation).

**Further information** In response to Will's comment:
Evaluating at $q=-1$ gives
$$ 1,0,1,-1,4,-2,13,-10,55,-40,241,-190,\ldots $$
Reducing modulo $1+q+q^2$ gives
$$1,0,1,1,1,1,5,3,5,19,15,19,\ldots$$
Reducing modulo $1+q^2$ gives 
$$1,0,1,-q,0,0,q,q-1,3,0,2q+3,-q-1,\ldots$$
Reducing modulo $(1-q^5)/(1-q)$ gives 
$$1,0,1,q^3,-q^3,0,0,0,0,-q^3-q-1,3,0,\ldots$$
Reducing modulo $1-q+q^2$ gives 
$$1,0,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$$

As requested by Jacques, I have put the first fifteen polynomials in a file which you
should be able to access here
[G2 polynomials](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbn/cspG2.txt)

I have put the first forty polynomials of a second example in a file which you
should be able to access here
[A1 polynomials](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbn/cspA1.txt)
These are $q$-analogues of the 
[Riordan numbers](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A005043)
The linear recurrence relation is given there as
$$ (n+1)*a[n] = (n - 1)*(2*a[n - 1] + 3*a[n - 2]) $$

Comment: If I put $q = 1$ I get $1,0,1,1,4,10,\dots$ and not $1,0,1,4,10,35,\dots$. 

Comment: Bruce, are you serious? I have in mind plenty of $q$-series sequences which have lack of recursion analogues (for example, the polynomials in the Peter Borwein conjectures). If you have in mind a linear recurrence relation, like the one for a non-$q$-version, than it might simply not exist at all: check with http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23437/ . In any case, the only way to search for such a recursion one has to know a hypergeometric expression for your polynomials; then a recipe could be to apply a $q$-version of Gosper-Zeilberger creative telescoping.

Comment: Wadim, thank you for your response. I accept that the way I have put the question is naive and also that I don't know that a linear recurrence exists. I am not sure that the method you outline is "the only way". The FRICAS team could try and guess a recurrence. The reason I think a recurrence may well exist is in my previous question. Finally I am not requiring a linear recurrence (but I am not sure what else would be sensible to ask for).

Comment: Bruce, I would really suggest you to write your sequence in a more explicit way. It is already hard to guess sequences for numbers having just 5-10 terms, while for the "$q$-numbers" (polynomials, of course) it is practically impossible. Why won't you bother the "FRICAS team"? (I have no idea who they are.)

Comment: Bruce, In my answer to Wadim Zudilin's related question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32978, I've mentioned an interesting phenomenon that occurs when you replace $q$ by a root of unity.

Comment: 8 terms are not enough for guessing software, especially if we know that the recurrence will be at least order 4 [there is not enough information in those 8 terms!].  Of course, posting more terms here would not be all that helpful either, since re-typing them would likely introduce errors.  Could you put them in a simple format in a simple text file and upload it somewhere? (like http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Jacques, Hopefully the first fifteen polynomials are now available from my home web page. Does this help?

Comment: @Bruce: got it, thanks.  Trying out a few things with Maple now, to see if I get anything.

Comment: @Bruce: I need 16 terms of the q=1 sequence to successfully guess the recurrence, so there is no chance of being able to do something sensible withc just 15 terms in the general case, unfortunately.  Looks like 20 or 25 terms might be needed to really get somewhere.

Comment: Jacques, Thanks a lot. I would need a new idea to compute 20-25 terms of this sequence. I have made a second sequence available. This second sequence should have a simpler recurrence so may need fewer terms anyway. However I can calculate many more terms of this second sequence (by a different method) if needed.

Comment: Jacques, I have now made the first forty terms of the second sequence available. I could compute the first seventy terms (maybe more) if required.

Comment: Bruce, sorry I didn't see the question in time.  Please send as many terms as you have (70 looks good, ideally as a comma separated list) to me by email if you are unwilling to install FriCAS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [FriCAS](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/), one can indeed guess a q-recurrence, given the first 50 terms or so. It is not nice, though.  The command issued is

`guessHolo(q)(cons(1, [qRiordan n for n in 1..60]), debug==true, safety==10)`

for the q-differential equation (a linear combination with polynomial coefficients of $f(x), f(qx),\dots,f(q^5 x)$, degree in $x$ is 6), or

`guessPRec(q)(cons(1, [qRiordan n for n in 1..48]), debug==true, safety==2)`

for the q-recurrence.